# cpanel function deldenyip() is not working

Tags: php, cpanel

https://192.168.0.0:2087/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=1&cpanel_jsonapi_module=Module&cpanel_jsonapi_func=deldenyip&user=username&ip=127.0.0.1

**I got error like this**

```
 Array ( [apiversion] => 1 [type] => event [module] => Module [func] => 
deldenyip [source] => module [data] => Array ( [result] => ) [event] => 
Array ( [reason] => Module::deldenyip() failed: Can't use string ("") as a 
subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at cpanel.pl line 1725. [result] 
=> 0 ) [error] => Module::deldenyip() failed: Can't use string ("") as a 
subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at cpanel.pl line 1725. )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine after using xmlapi class file to call cpanel methods